# Instagram photo sharing

Tags: ios, instagram

I am trying to post photo in mostly all social networking sites. My facebook, twitter, linkedin, flickr, etc have been completed. But i am unable to post my photo in instagram. I have tried this code, using this code i can post photo but photo is posting using camera. I want to post photo from my phone gallery.

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://camera"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

Is there any way to post photo in instagram from my app?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/), that's the right way to do it. Maybe you didn't give Instagram access to the photo library?

Comment: thanks. i will try this thing.